# Calculating the ols coefficient beta without function lm

Tags: r, linear-regression

How can I calculate the OLS coefficient in R without the function lm.
Formula: ß = (X'X)^-1*X'y

```
   X <- cbind(runif(1000000), rnorm(1000000), rchisq(1000000,50))
   y <- 100 * X[,1] + 200 * X[,2] + rnorm(nrow(X), 0, 10)
```

Would be really grateful for help since I have no idea how I can do this

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually for homework.
The problem is I dont know what X' means

Comment: Not so sure about having stackoverflow do your homework for you, but X' stands for the transpose of X.

Answer (score 1):

It's basic linear algebra for OLS. You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

```
set.seed(123)
X <- cbind(runif(1000000), rnorm(1000000), rchisq(1000000,50))
y <- 100 * X[,1] + 200 * X[,2] + rnorm(nrow(X), 0, 10)


# (X'X)^-1*X'y

# basic matrix algebra
solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% y)

# crossprod for numeric stability
crossprod(solve(crossprod(X)), crossprod(X,y))

# same in lm()
lm(y~0+X)
```

If your linear model has an intercept

```
x <- cbind(1, X)

# (X'X)^-1*X'y
solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% (t(x) %*% y)
crossprod(solve(crossprod(x)), crossprod(x,y))
lm(y~X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, including gradient decent. Kudos also to [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/regression-via-gradient-descent-in-r/).

```
x0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1) # Intercept
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(8,4,3,1,8)
x <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1,x2))
y <- as.matrix(c(3,7,5,11,14))

# (X'X)^-1 X'y
beta1 = solve(t(x)%*%x) %*% t(x)%*%y 

# R's regression command
beta2 = summary(lm(y ~ x[, 2:3]))

# Gradient decent
m <- nrow(y)
grad <- function(x, y, theta) {
  gradient <- (1/m)* (t(x) %*% ((x %*% t(theta)) - y))
  return(t(gradient))
}

# Define gradient descent update algorithm
grad.descent <- function(x, maxit){
  theta <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0), nrow=1) # Initialize the parameters

  alpha = .05 # set learning rate
  for (i in 1:maxit) {
    theta <- theta - alpha  * grad(x, y, theta)   
  }
  return(theta)
}

# Results without feature scaling
print(grad.descent(x,2000))
beta1
beta2
```